# How to setup a cloud database in Unity?

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, storage

I am pretty new to Unity and coding in general, and I am developing my first unity2d game!

My game is going to also have a level editor and publisher so I have to store the level data on an external online database! The level data is just a simple string :)

I have been watching different tutorials with many different options. My question is what is the best option to setup a simple database in Unity?

I am planning for this to be an Android game, but I thought of using WebGL in order to test it before actually making a stable Android version, so I'd prefer a Database accessible from WebGL and Android

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry your question is to broad and mostly opinion based and therefore offtopic here on StackOverflow. Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no best way.  Just pick one.